# get count of partitions in a kafka topic with scala 2.12

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

With scala 2.11 and spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 I could do

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster

val params = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "my_group_id",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)
val topicsSet = Array("topicA", "topicB")
val kafkaCluster = new KafkaCluster(params)
val kafkaPartitions = kafkaCluster.getPartitions(topicsSet).right.get
val kafkaPartitionsCount = kafkaPartitons.size
```

Now with scala 2.12 and spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12 there is no KafkaCluster. How do I migrate this piece of code to find number of topic partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Spark for this. You can use [`KafkaConsumer.listTopics()`](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#listTopics--) to get a Map of topic names to a list of partitions.